# Can you pass a dynamic variable into a Meteor blaze template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I saw the response to this stackoverflow post: [Is there a way to pass variables into templates in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128053/is-there-a-way-to-pass-variables-into-templates-in-meteor)

The post only shows how to pass in a static value into blaze template. See the following example - I'm trying to pass in user.username into the template `cookieTemplate`

```
<template name="userTemplate">
  <p> Wellcome {{user.username}} </p>
  {{#each user.profile.cookies}}
    {{> cookieTemplate username={{user.username}} }}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="cookieTemplate">
  {{username}} has cookie {{this.cookieName}}
</template>
```

I know that I could potentially do this with `Session.set('username', blah)`, but I was wondering if I can pass a dynamic variable into template?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to yours is just to pass the user object to the template

```
{{> cookieTemplate user=user }}
```

and use it inside the template as

```
{{user.username}}
```

or you write down some helper to create a data object with relevant attributes like:

```
Template.userTemplate.helpers({
  get_user: function() {
    return { username: Template.instance().user.username }
}
```

and then call the template with

```
{{> cookieTemplate user=get_user }}
```

and use the value by

```
{{user.username}}
```

I made something similar (helper function) as a MeteorPad to this thread
[Access an object's property names in a Blaze template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220610/access-an-objects-property-names-in-a-blaze-template/31221316#31221316)

Maybe it helps you

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and might already be doing so.

In general if you are getting your data through auto publish or pub-sub, the data is considered reactive. Every time there is an update on the collection in anyway this update will be pushed to the template.

For your case, if you got the data through `currentUser` or `Meteor.user()` it would be the same case.